# Excel if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using this if Statement to check to see if a cell is blank. If it is blank than it leave it blank. Once something is enter into the sell it creates a ticket number. So that would be in E2. In E3 i need the same if statement but +1 added on to the number.

Here is the if statement =IF(ISBLANK($B2),"","AG"&10000)
E2 would be AG10000
E3 i would like to be AG10001

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want consecutive numbers to be assigned to tickets? e.g if 2 rows are blank and previous entry at say row 5 ended with AG10003, do you want the next entry after two rows in row 7 to be AG10004 ? If yes it's bit complicated, if no you can simply modify your formula to =IF(ISBLANK($B2),"","AG"&10000+ROW()-2) Assuming you start your data in row 2

Comment: I get a an error on the ROW() when i use your if statement

Comment: You may like to post the exact formula you are using and a screenshot of the error. ROW() just returns the Row number of cell in which this function is executed. Assuming you put this in Row 2, original formula is expected to give you sequential list starting from 10000 incremented by 1 for each next row. What happens when you just put =ROW() in any cell, do you get the row number of that cell therein? Alternatively try this too =IF(ISBLANK($B2),"","AG"&10000+ROW(1:1)) and drag it down.